# Objective-C / ALAssetsLibrary - Find images informations and Exif informations

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to use the ALAssetsLibrary Class for retrieve the list of the photos inside the device and the relative informations about them. I have implemented a method that reveal correctly the number of images, but at the moment i don't know how can i find photos informations how width, height, orientation ecc…
This is the code that i'm using:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){
                NSString *description = [asset description];
                NSLog(@"description %@", description);

            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

Actually if i log the my NSString "description" variable, i receive these informations (for one example image):

> "description ALAsset - Type:Photo,
>   URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=766424BD-D28D-47F9-8E0F-AD8F19C4C732&ext=JPG"

Now, i need to understand how find the others information (width, height, name ect..) and if there is the possibility to access to the EXIF informations of the images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Instead of logging the description of the asset, you want to log the meta data of the default representation of the asset. The following will get you an NSDictionary containing the metadata for the image. Then you can access properties like height, width, etc with standard objectForKey calls.

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){

                NSDictionary *data = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];
                NSLog(@"%@",data);
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

Comment: Ah damn! I were really too close. Thanks @0x7fffffff ! Is there a way for ask only for example the width? Or i have to take the data variable and take only the pieces that i need from it?

Comment: Thank you very much @0x7fffffff! Your example is clear and simple!